# GPSD Not Responding to New Connections

Tags: python, sockets, gps, gpsd

I'm using GPSd v3.17-5 from Ubuntu's Bionic repo.

I'm having an issue where GPSd simply refuses to respond to new client connections.

Below is a dump from `lsof` that shows how `gpsmon` is connected (you can see both gpsd and gpsmon have established connections), but my `python` connection is only established on the Python side.

```
root@machine:~# lsof -n -P -i TCP:2947
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd    1 root   57u  IPv6  39371      0t0  TCP [::1]:2947 (LISTEN)
systemd    1 root   58u  IPv4  40365      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:2947 (LISTEN)
gpsd     949 gpsd    4u  IPv6  39371      0t0  TCP [::1]:2947 (LISTEN)
gpsd     949 gpsd    5u  IPv4  40365      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:2947 (LISTEN)
gpsd     949 gpsd    7u  IPv4  59781      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:2947->127.0.0.1:41656 (ESTABLISHED)
gpsmon  3289 root    3u  IPv4  60651      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:41656->127.0.0.1:2947 (ESTABLISHED)
python  3387 root    5u  IPv4  61892      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:41662->127.0.0.1:2947 (ESTABLISHED)
```

If I kill `gpsmon` it won't be able to reconnect either and just sits around.

```
root@machine:~# lsof -n -P -i TCP:2947
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd    1 root   57u  IPv6  39371      0t0  TCP [::1]:2947 (LISTEN)
systemd    1 root   58u  IPv4  40365      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:2947 (LISTEN)
gpsd     949 gpsd    4u  IPv6  39371      0t0  TCP [::1]:2947 (LISTEN)
gpsd     949 gpsd    5u  IPv4  40365      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:2947 (LISTEN)
python  3508 root    5u  IPv4  64143      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:55999->127.0.0.1:2947 (ESTABLISHED)
gpsmon  6157 root    3u  IPv4  64311      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:41678->127.0.0.1:2947 (ESTABLISHED)
```

I have tried disabling `gpsd.socket` via `systemctl` but my results are no different after a reboot. The first client connection seems fine, but after that it's a crap shoot.

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this. Does anyone have any idea where to even start? 
There are no errors or any messages that something is wrong in `journalctl -u gpsd`.

Is there something better out there than GPSd? It appears to be the defacto standard, but there are quite a few shortcomings. My biggest requirement is I can't manually specify the GPS device as this is part of a headless service.

Thanks for any help/direction/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

After monitoring `syslog` I noticed when I plug in my GPS device, `ModemManager` spit out a warning that it couldn't create a modem for my device.

```
Oct  4 23:03:47 ubuntu ModemManager[681]: <info>  [device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2] creating modem with plugin 'u-blox' and '1' ports
Oct  4 23:03:47 ubuntu ModemManager[681]: <warn>  Could not grab port (tty/ttyACM0): 'Cannot add port 'tty/ttyACM0', unhandled serial type'
Oct  4 23:03:47 ubuntu ModemManager[681]: <warn>  Couldn't create modem for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2': Failed to find primary AT port
```

I guess `ModemManager` would end up taking over the device and GPSd would lose connection and block forever waiting for a response. This is all a hunch but disabling `ModemManager` resolved all my issues!

```
systemctl disable ModemManager.service
```